# Spring Boot Bean 'Required bean of type that could not be found'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, orm, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have been working on learning how to use spring data and I have created a very simple project to test it.  The folder structure and applicationcontext.xml is shown here:[applicationcontext.xml and folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VldmM.jpg)
The error I am getting is shown here:[console error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtFWt.jpg)
.
I have the applicationContext on my classpath and have a bean of that class declared, any idea as to what my problem could be ? Thank you.

EDIT:
I have updated my post to show the main class and the dao class, as well as my pom.xml contents (as at this point, I am wondering if I need to include another dependency . . . )
[main class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rn68.jpg)
[dao (repository)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghoyh.jpg)

Comment: Can you add you spring boot main class?? You dont need a appcontxt xml.. Just add Component or Repository annotation on your UserRepository, remove your appctx file and try.

Comment: Hi Praneeth - I added the main class for you to inspect.  Let me know if you spot my error

Comment: Are you running this through a test case.. I see the an exception caught through TestContextManager in the logs. If yes then add the SpringBoot Test case and the test configuration.

Comment: Good eye Praneeth! However, when I run the project as a spring boot project (without tests), I still get the following error: 
Description:

Field userRepository in com.connor.controller.RegisterController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

Comment: Looks like you have not created a Bean EntityManagerFactory bean. Are you using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency. If yes then Spring boot creates a default EntityManagerFactory for you, if not then you need to register a EntityManagerFactory yourself.. Add this in a configuration class and try. See here to create one http://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa

Comment: Praneeth, thank you so much for your help! This resolved my error.  Now it tells me that I need to create a bean that is of type DataSource.  Should I create this in a similar fashion (with the @bean annotation in the config file?) Thank you so much.

Comment: Nope.. Just add a @Autowired on that method that will fix it if you already have a datasource configuration in you spring boot properties file.

Comment: Hi Praneeth, I am now getting this error: Parameter 0 of method entityManagerFactory in com.connor.util.AppConfigUtil required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
 - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
 - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager'


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.

Comment: My application.properties file is as follows: connor.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/craigslist
connor.datasource.username=dbadmin
connor.datasource.password=********
connor.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true

Comment: Add a TransactionManager bean. 
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
    new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
}

Inorder to avoid all these problem try creating the project from start.spring.io

Answer (score 0):

I miss the following line in your application log:

... o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : **Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]**

So I assume your applicationContext.xml file is not loaded at all.

Either add

```
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
```

to your application class or add the

```
@Repository
```

annotation to your UserRepository class.

In my opinion you should avoid mixing Java and XML Spring configuration if possible.

Comment: Hi Hardi, thanks for your input; as I mentioned I am beginning learning spring.  However, if I autowire another bean and define it via xml - it can be injected without error.  Thus, I suspect the .xml file is being loaded.  However, as you suggested, I am moving to entirely java config from here on out and have removed any xml.  Thank you for your help!